# Session capabilities difference than local as compare to perfecto appium capabilities

Tags: appium, perfecto

I am doing android automation testing with `appium` using `local simulator` and `perfecto android` device

If I hit below local URL

`http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/session/dd607ee0-6ba8-4d71-9459-3252d896153e`

then I am getting this response https://gist.github.com/pareshgami/8434f86df2ec2e68167c097548e591ab

but when I run same thing with perfecto android and If I hit below URL I am getting complete different response from perfecto.

`http://partners.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub/session/10c767b1-05d6-4a41-866e-364cacd48600`

Perfecto Response Gist

https://gist.github.com/pareshgami/112dc614787f34c8ed7c50e64a2e1573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set one more capability

```
capabilities.setCapability("enableAppiumBehavior", true);
```

https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/PD/New+architecture+for+Appium+testing+on+Android+%7C+Early+access